# Android app startup blank/crash on touch

Tags: java, android, crash, processing

I am developing an Android application using the Processing IDE. On my Nexus 7, everything seems to work fine, but when I launch the app on other smartphone devices (yes everything basic such as the proper OS version, RAM, etc are more than sufficient) It starts up as a blnk screen...and the moment I tap the screen.. the app crashes. here is my printout of my logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22569):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  590):   Force finishing activity processing.test.main_ebook3/.Main_EBook3
I/WindowManager(  590): Screenshot Window{42a7b640 u0 processing.test.main_ebook3/processing.test.main_ebook3.Main_EBook3} was monochrome(ffcccccc)! mSurfaceLayer=21125 minLayer=21000 maxLayer=21125
I/ActivityManager(  590): Config changes=480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw384dp w384dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.29}
I/InputReader(  590): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  590): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='touch_dev', size 768x1280, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
D/PhoneStatusBar(  672): mSettingsPanelGravity = 55
I/WindowManager(  590): Screen frozen for +153ms due to Window{42504da0 u0 NavigationBar}
W/ActivityManager(  590): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4231e510 u0 processing.test.main_ebook3/.Main_EBook3 t946 f}
W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 9238): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
I/Choreographer( 9238): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1500K, 33% free 30213K/44492K, paused 7ms+11ms, total 161ms
I/ActivityManager(  590): Start proc com.google.android.gms for service com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService: pid=22711 uid=10023 gids={50023, 3003, 1007, 3002, 3001, 1028, 1015, 3007, 2001, 3006}
D/EventWidget(13557): onReceive 1x1 - start to update all widgets... - hu.jimsoft.eventcountdownwidget.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE
D/EventWidget(13557): onReceive 2x1 - start to update all widgets... - hu.jimsoft.eventcountdownwidget.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE
D/EventWidget(13557): updating widget: ID 52
D/EventWidget(13557): 1x1 1x1
D/EventWidget(13557): 2014.05.09 00:00
D/EventWidget(13557): diff#2:31 0 0 0 164 1 744
D/EventWidget(13557): onReceive 3x1 - start to update all widgets... - hu.jimsoft.eventcountdownwidget.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE
D/YouTube MDX( 6691): discoveryRequestChanged : DiscoveryRequest{ selector=MediaRouteSelector{ controlCategories=[com.google.cast.CATEGORY_CAST, com.google.cast.CATEGORY_CAST_APP_NAME:Pandora_App] }, activeScan=true, isValid=true }
I/MultiDex(22711): load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk, forceReload=false)
D/dalvikvm(29762): GC_CONCURRENT freed 925K, 12% free 13183K/14952K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 40ms
D/dalvikvm(29762): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
D/dalvikvm(22711): GC_CONCURRENT freed 153K, 2% free 9317K/9508K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 21ms
I/MultiDex(22711): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-2.apk.classes2.zip
I/MultiDex(22711): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-2.apk.classes2.zip of size 1547068
D/Finsky  (29762): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
D/GCM     ( 9654): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
D/dalvikvm(22711): GC_CONCURRENT freed 249K, 3% free 9478K/9760K, paused 5ms+7ms, total 26ms
I/Process (22569): Sending signal. PID: 22569 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  590): Process processing.test.main_ebook3 (pid 22569) has died.
I/WindowState(  590): WIN DEATH: Window{42a7b640 u0 processing.test.main_ebook3/processing.test.main_ebook3.Main_EBook3}
W/WindowManager(  590): Force-removing child win Window{428d03b8 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{42a7b640 u0 processing.test.main_ebook3/processing.test.main_ebook3.Main_EBook3}
W/WindowManager(  590): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  590): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@43526078 does not exist
W/WindowManager(  590):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7897)
W/WindowManager(  590):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7888)
W/WindowManager(  590):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1040)
W/WindowManager(  590):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:493)
W/WindowManager(  590):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/WindowState(  590): WIN DEATH: null
D/dalvikvm( 9238): GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 22% free 13685K/17540K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 49ms
D/YouTube MDX( 6691): discoveryRequestChanged : null
I/ActivityManager(  590): Killing 22711:com.google.android.gms/u0a23 (adj 9): cached #9
W/ActivityManager(  590): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.playlog.service.PlayLogBrokerService in 80000ms
D/ConnectivityService(  590): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
D/ConnectivityService(  590): Done.
D/ConnectivityService(  590): Setting timer for 720seconds
```

Comment: Can you get a basic, sample project to run on both your Nexus and the other devices? That's where I would start.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573931/android-service-android-os-binderproxy-error

Comment: The issue was a class function made for Processing.Specifically, it had to do with setting the orientation to landscape. I decided to implement this directly in the manifest file which solved my issue.