# Error : BinderProxy@b4d6acb0

Tags: java, android

While running my project, I am getting the ***BinderProxy@b4d6acb0 error***. Can I know the reason of this error. I have pasted my code below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.custom_activity);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

   swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
   swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//fetchTimelineAsync(0);
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
//startActivity(i);
swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
adapter.clear();
method(); 
}


});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573931/android-service-android-os-binderproxy-error

Comment: That's not the clear answer.

Comment: Post the complete error message including the stack trace, because just "Error: BinderProxy@b4d6acb0" is not enough information to know what's wrong.

Comment: ActivityRecord{b4d10190 token=android.os.BinderProxy@b4d0f8f8 {com.example.powermeterdm/com.example.powermeterdm.activity.CustomFragment}}